# right-cancellative property and surjectivity

Tags: functions

I was trying to prove that if $f:X\to Y$ is a function (between sets $X$ and $Y$), then $f$ is surjective if and only if $f$ is right-cancellative: For all $g,h:Y\to Z$, if $g\circ f=h\circ f$, then $g=h$.

I proved trivially the statement that if $f$ is surjective, and $g\circ f=h\circ f$, then $g=h$. But the converse part: if for all $g,h$, $g\circ f=h\circ f$ implies $g=h$, then $f$ is surjective, I am less sure about.

So the questions:

1. I attempted to prove it by assuming (for the sake of contradiction) that if $g\circ f = h\circ f \Rightarrow g=h$ for some non-surjective $f$, there is a contradiction. Namely, if we choose $g,h$ so that $g=h$ for all $y\in Y$ except for $\eta$ where $\eta$ is chosen so that no $x\in X$ satisfies $f(x)=\eta$, then we have a contradiction $g=h$. Is this proof correct?
2. I would like to prove it without contradiction, if possible. So, what is the contraposition of the statement: If for all $g,h:Y\to Z$, $g\circ f=h\circ f$ implies $g=h$, then $f$ is surjective?

Thanks bunch in advance.

Comment: The contrapositive is "If $f$ is not surjective, then there is a set $Z$ and functions $g,h \colon Y \to Z$ with $g\neq h$ but $g\circ f = h\circ f$".

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want a proof that is not based on contradiction?

Comment: drhab: personal preference, I guess. I've always been told that a direct, constructive proof is more desirable than an indirect, contradiction proof, so I always try to find one (a constructive, direct one) whenever I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 1)

You are almost correct here.

You should mention explicit functions $g$ and $h$ with $g\circ f=h\circ f\wedge g\neq h$.

Let $\eta\notin\text{im}f$ and let $g,h:Y\to\{0,1\}$.

This with $g$ prescribed by $y\mapsto 0$ and $h$ prescribed by $y\mapsto 0$ if $y\neq\eta$ and $y\mapsto1$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The functions $g f$ and $h f$ are only defined on $S=\{f(x):x\in X\}.$

(1). If  $Z$ has at least $2$ members and if $S\ne Y$:  There exists $y_1\in Y$ \ $S$ and there exist $z_1,z_2\in Z$ with $z_1\ne z_2.$ So for any $g:Y\to Z,$ we can let $h(y)=g(y)$ when $y_1\ne y\in S$; and let $h(y_1)=z_1$ if $g(y_1)\ne z_1,$ and let $h(y_1)=z_2$ if $g(y_1)=z_1.$ Then $g f=h f$ but $g\ne h.$

(2). If $S=Y$ then for any functions $g,h$ from $Y$ to $Z$ we have $$g=h\iff \forall y\in Y\;[g(y)=h(y))]\iff$$ $$\iff  \forall y\in Y\;\forall x\in X\;[f(x)=y\implies g f (x)=h f(y)]\iff$$ $$\iff \forall x\in X\;\forall y\in Y\;[f(x)=y\implies \; g f(x)=h f(x)]\iff$$ $$ \forall x\in X\;[g f (x)=h f(x)]\iff$$  $$\iff g f= h f.$$ The second line is equivalent to the first because $S=Y$.

Comment: Under (2) it is proved here that $f$ is right-cancellable if it is surjective ($gf=hf\implies g=h$, the other side of this is direct). The OP mentions that he proved this allready himself "trivially". If I understand him correctly then he is actually asking for a proof of the opposite that does not depend on contradiction.

Comment: Well anyway i did both directions without a proof by contradiction.